# Twitter API, Linked In API in PHP

Tags: php, twitter, linkedin-api

I am looking for a simple script that I can use to send some text to Twitter, and Linked in.

The objective is to be able to have a simple sample PHP script that looks something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Twitter and Linked In API</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php $dummy_txt = 'Hello world! from me'; ?>
  <div id="tweet">Tweet</div>
  <div id="sendto_li">Send to Linked In</div>
  $(body).ready(function(){
     $('#tweet').click(function(){
        //post data to server
     });
     $('#sendto_li').click(function(){
        //post data to server
     });
  });
  </body>
</html>

//Server side
<?php
  function tweet(){
  }

  function sendto_linkedin(){
  }
?>
```

Cabn anyone help with writing the server side functions that will encapsulate the Twitter and LinkedIn API?

Comment: You're asking to write your code? Do it yourself or hire someone? Is my first reaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For twitter have a look here for PHP script. [php-twitter](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php)

I don't think LinkedIn has a public API but it has an API. You would need to contact them to get that information.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter currently recommends [tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth) and we use it. It works well

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how LinkedIn works, but for Twitter, either you have to use oAuth to post for the user or just use a link of this format:

```
<a href=”http://twitter.com/home?status=STATUS”>Tweet</a>
```

and then the user just has to post the status on twitter's site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use oAuth for Twitter and if it's your LinkedIn account you can link the two accounts to share the same feed. LinkedIn API link http://developer.linkedin.com/community/apis;jsessionid=0386306DE923BEFCB325BD1E9B6F7ABB.node0 Would need to request API Access